# Остаток, останки

Tags: этимология

Существуют ли в старославянском/русском еще слова с "чередованием" т->н:
 остаток -> останок
петие -> пение?

Answer (score 1):

[Этимологический словарь русского языка](http://endic.ru/rusethy/Ostanki-2593.html)

**ОСТАНКИ *(только мн. ч.)***

> Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. Форма мн. ч. сущ. останъкъ «остаток», суф.
>   производного от останыи «оставшийся», страдат. прич. прош. вр. от
>   остати «остаться», преф. образования от стати. См. стать (1)}},
>   <<остаток.

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка.
Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

---

Никакого ПЕТИЯ не обнаружено как класса.

---

**ПЕТЬ**

> Общеслав. Объясняется как каузатив к *пить*. *Пою* «заставляю, даю
>   пить» дало *пою* «воспеваю, пою песнь» в связи с языческим обрядом
>   жертвенного возлияния и одновременного исполнения гимнов. См. *паять,
>   ваять.*

Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение
слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

[**ПЕНИЕ**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> Происходит от глагола петь, от праслав. *pěti, от кот. в числе прочего
>   произошли: др.-русск. пѣти, пою, ст.-слав. пѣти, поѭ (др.-греч. ᾄδειν,
>   ψάλλειν), русск. петь, пою, укр. пі́яти, пі́ю, белор. пець, пе́ю,
>   болг. поя́, пе́я, сербохорв. пjе̏вати, словенск. pẹ́ti, pójem, чешск.
>   zpívat, словацк. spievať, польск. рiаć, pieję, śpiewać, др.-польск.
>   рiеć, роję, в.-луж. spěwać, н.-луж. spiwaś. Отсюда: певе́ц, пету́х,
>   пе́сня. Дальнейшие сближения недостоверны. Предполагали связь с греч.
>   παιάν, ион. παιήων, атт. παιών, -ῶνος «пеан, гимн в честь Аполлона,
>   который начинается словами ἰη παιήων». О. Трубачёв комментирует: слав.
>   pěti, роjǫ должно объясняться как первонач. каузатив от глаг. piti,
>   русск. пить, ср. тождество форм пою́ «даю пить» и пою́ «издаю голосом
>   музыкальные звуки». Переход значений «поить» > «петь, воспевать»
>   восходит, т. обр., к языческому обряду жертвенного возлияния. Ср.
>   родство др.-инд. juhóti «льёт» и hávatē «призывает».

Использованы данные словаря М. Фасмера  с комментариями О. Н. Трубачёва.

---

[Для суффиксального словообразования существительных от глаголов характерны следующие суффиксы: -ниj (петь < пение)...](https://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37380.php?ELEMENT_ID=37380&PAGEN_1=5)

Добавим: знать < знание, уметь < умение.

Больше я ничего сходного по словообразованию не обнаружила. Да, и никакого "чередования": основа инфинитива + суффикс.

См. пары слов в статье про ударение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]